# sudo asks for password in cronjob script but the same script works without password in terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kubectl, minikube

I have added a script in `/etc/sudoers` file.

```sh
user ALL=(ALL)     NOPASSWD:/home/user/project/execute.sh
```

After that I have added the same script in users crontab as shown below:

```sh
*/1 * * * * /home/user/project/execute.sh > /home/user/cronjob-logs/`date +\%FT\%T`-cron.log 2>&1
```

There is a command in the script which can only be run using `sudo`. But since I added the script in sudoers file, it works in the terminal without password. But it throws "permission denied" error in crontab. Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I see you tagged kubectl and minikube to this case but you didn't mentioned it on the question itself. Do you mind clarifying it?

Comment: The command which I am running in the script is kubectl commands which communicates with minikube cluster. Thank for looking into the issue :). I was able to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue by adding sudo before the script in crontab as shown below:

```sh
*/1 * * * * sudo /home/user/project/execute.sh > /home/user/cronjob-logs/date +\%FT\%T-cron.log 2>&1
```